# How can i add record to some JSON file in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was trying to add some records in JSON file by using angular js but i was getting some error ,may be due to my bad code.

Please tell me, how should i do this?

**This my plunker**
[sample code in this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/m0m6cVfqAj8ey4Y35YXG?p=preview)

```
 myApp.controller('ToddlerCtrl', function ($scope,$http) {

  $http.get('taskList.json').success(function (data){
    $scope.tasks = data;
});

   $scope.addEmp = function(){

    $scope.bla="sijs";
    $scope.tasks.push({ task:$scope.empName, priority:$scope.empCity, status:$scope.empState });


  var dataObj = {
            task : $scope.empName,
            priority : $scope.empCity,
            status:$scope.empState
    };  
    var res = $http.post('taskList.json', dataObj);
    res.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.message = data;
    });
    res.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert( "failure message: " + JSON.stringify({data: data}));
    }); 

}




});
```

Comment: sending an `http` `POST` request to a `JSON` file won't add the data in it. You should create a backend service that accepts the data and writes it to the file. You probably should use something like mongodb rather than a JSON file.

Comment: @TJ Hi , that is cool, I know.  But in this case, You mean to say that there is no any option to write json file from javascript??  without going to backend.

Comment: If you already know, I wonder why did you post the question without trying to implement a backend service...

Comment: @TJ Hi , that is cool, I know.  But in this case, You mean to say that there is no any option to write json file from javascript??  without going to backend.

Comment: If you just want to store some data at client side better you look into `localStorage`... JavaScript has lots of limitations accessing file system due to security issues... (*somebody opens your website and you write a malicious file into their computer..*)

Comment: @TJ : thanks bro, localStorage solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The controller code is good, the only issue is that your form to add the new tasks are not within the div where you defined your controller so it will not inherit the scope from it, therefore the bindings empName, empCity, empState and addEmp won't work as they are part of the ToddlerCtrl.

Your html needs to look like this:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.7" data-semver="1.2.7" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.7/angular.js"></script>
     <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hardi's Task Analyzer</h1>

    <div ng-controller="ToddlerCtrl">
      <h2>Toddlers</h2>

      <!-- Add new task form -->
     <label>Add  Task Name</label><input type="text" ng-model="empName">
      <label>Add Priority</label><input type="text" ng-model="empCity">
      <label>Add Status</label><input type="text" ng-model="empState">
     <button  ng-click="addEmp()">Add <i class="icon-plus"></i></button>
      <br /><br />
      {{empName}}

      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Task Name</th>
          <th>Priority</th>
          <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="task in tasks">
          <td>{{task.task}}</td>
          <td>{{task.priority}}</td>
          <td>{{task.status}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Please see updated plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/pMCFSilYUC1QHH6FUl6G?p=preview

This will add them to the list in the view and the controller, however to add them to the JSON file you will need to implement a server side action using NodeJS, ASP.NET, Java, Ruby or some other server side technology to access and edit the file. You will then need to add a save button to send the new list to the server to update the JSON file. It will be better to implement this with a database rather than a JSON file though to manage concurrency easily.

Comment: HI, here i don't only want to push record temporarily.  I was looking to add record permanently in json file without going to backend.

Comment: Where will the JSON file be stored? Will multiple people need to access it?

Comment: Json file will be stored in Project folder itself. And yes,multiple people need to access it.

Comment: Then you need a backend, you can only save changes to local files using Javascript in the browser not on the server. You should use a database for this as managing multiple people accessing a single file can become very complicated